# Attacking and defending at the same time with two weapons

Tags: savage-worlds

If a fighter has two weapons, can he use one to attack and the other for defense with a Full-Defense maneuver?

I know that Defense does not apply in this case because it requires that the "*character’s only regular action is to defend*".

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is entirely possible. Maneuvers like Full-Defense [are equivalent to an attack](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40742&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=).

> Full Defense does require a hand to use; after all, it's still a
>   Fighting attack.

Bonuses and penalties apply in the same way to both the attack and the full-defense, but it is important to note that the full-defense is equivalent to an attack (so [it is affected by Two-Fisted](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40804&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=), even if the description of the edge says "When *attacking* with a weapon in each hand..." and the character is not *attacking* but *defending* with that weapon).

Some examples (based on these [examples from the official forum](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40804&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=)):

- A character with no edges attacks with the good hand and does full-defense with the off-hand. The attack is at -2 (multi-action penalty, MAP); the full-defense Fighting roll is at -2 (+2 full-defense, -2 MAP, -2 off-hand), and the result substitutes Parry if it is higher.
- A character with Two-Fisted attacks with the off-hand and does full-defense with the good hand. The attack is at -2 (off-hand); the full-defense Fighting roll is at +2 (standard full-defense) and the result substitutes Parry if it is higher.
- A character with Two-Fisted and Ambidextrous attacks and does full-defense. The attack is at +0; the full-defense Fighting roll is at +2 (standard full-defense) and the result substitutes Parry if it is higher.
- A character with Two-Fisted and Ambidextrous does a wild attack with one hand and full-defense with the other. The attack is at +2 (wild attack); [the full-defense Fighting roll is at +4](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40804&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=) (+2 full-defense, +2 wild attack) and the result substitutes Parry if it is higher. The resulting Parry is then subtracted -2 (wild attack).